# Is possible send bundle args to ALL fragments using Navigation Drawer Layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, bundle

I have a navigation drawer with fifteen fragments to be switched between them, I want a common data to exist between this fragment, so I only need to pull it from the database once and use it in all my fragments, is there any way to send a Bundle for all my Navigation fragments?

Currently, I can only send to the first fragment (the one at the beginning, as follows in the code below), I want to send to all fragments of the navigation view ...
Should I use SharedPreferences? but the data is always changing (whenever the app opens).

```java
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_cad_bov, R.id.nav_attBoi, R.id.nav_acomp,
                R.id.nav_manejo, R.id.nav_patology, R.id.nav_desp, R.id.nav_ven, R.id.nav_meus_anu,
                R.id.nav_meus_anun_ed, R.id.nav_cap, R.id.nav_comp, R.id.nav_tuto, R.id.nav_editInfo, R.id.nav_logout).setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("amount", "Katinguele"); // Send to start fragment, i need send to ALL fragments
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation, bundle);

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Comment: You can use `sharedViewModel` across all the fragments

Comment: But this method makes my variable persistent in storage, correct? this is a danger, because I use this variable to check if the user is premium or not, despite testing this also in the security rules of firebase

Comment: Which method you're talking about?

Comment: I mistook SharedViewModel for Preferences, I'm trying to implement SharedViewModel at the moment, without success so far, can you put your comment as an answer for me to assign as correct? I believe that what I want is what you said.

Comment: Sure, let me add the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a `sharedViewModel` across all the fragments.

```
public class SharedtViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<String> amount;

    public void init()
    {
        amount = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount)
    {
        amount.setValue(amount);
    }
   
    public LiveData<String> getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Set the amount value from your Activity.

```
SharedViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel.class);
viewModel.setAmount(amount);
```

At the end, in every Fragment, you can observe it as follows:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    public void onActivityCreated() {
        SharedViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        model.getAmount().observe(this, { amount ->
           // Anything here
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you use `.observe` instead of simply get? Observe is a listener?

Comment: @DjongaNelsonLontrowski To Observe changes. but if you don't want to observe changes, you can change it with `String amount = model.getAmount().getValue();`

Comment: Exist a big impact on my performance and/or memory when i use this `.observe`?